# Trying to get react.rb template to render in opal using opal-jquery, was working now it's not

Tags: jquery, ruby, opalrb, react.rb

I admit this is similar to a previous question of mine but it's not quite the same. 
Since I'm using ajax requests in the end I decided to add opal-jquery to my stack, (unless you know an easier way) and switched to using the `Document.ready?` function provided by it.

My function now looks like this:

```
def render_component component,mount_point
   React.render React.create_element(component), Element.find[mount_point][0]
end
```

and I call it like this:

```
Document.ready? do
    render_component LoginForm, '#view_port'
end
```

The problem is that before this was working and now, it's not, I'm getting an `Uncaught NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil` error, it was working and then it just suddenly started doing this.

The error is because for some reason  `Element.find[mount_point]` is returning `nil` and I don't know why. It should be running after the dom is loaded so the mount point `'#view_port'` should exist; it definitely exists in the dom as you can see here:

```
<body>
  <section id="main">
    <section id="view_port">  
    </section>
  </section>

<div class="hiddendiv common"></div>
</body>
```

I've even tried wrapping it in `window.addEventListener("load", function () {}` but to no effect.

Why is it now not working? what have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, The problem is that the `Element['#view_port']` inside the `render_component` function was being called before `Document.ready?` and so was returning nil. Why this was I don't know, It should work, but it wasn't, so there you go.

Another problem which is worth mentioning (slightly related) was that trying `Element['#view_port'][0]` to get the native object results in the error `Uncaught TypeError: b.toLowerCase is not a function` so you can't use Jquery to get native dom elements, which means your stuck with `document.getElementById('view_port')`.